# Why does sublime text editor 3 autocomplete when I press return?

Tags: code-snippets, sublimetext3

When I am working in sublime text when I press "enter/return" a highlighted blue autocomplete section appears that reads:

```
div> (element)
```

And if I hit enter a snippet of "div>" appears, which is utterly annoying and useless.  Now, I know about snippets, etc...and how to create them, but I have not created any snippets that are set to autocomplete when I press enter (and I don't know how to for that matter), but this is just annoying.  Imagine editing your php and you keep getting this piece of code:

```
div> ~then you hit enter and the autocomplete shows up and...
div> ~then you hit again...and
div> ~kind of annoying right?
```

That's where I'm at.  I originally thought it was a snippet I created by accident but it isn't.  I removed all my snippets and the feature is still here as annoying as ever.  Any ideas on what this might be?  It autocompletes when I hit enter/return.  Is this some feature of sublime text 3?  What could this be?

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behavior in Sublime Text 3. To change it, open your user preferences (`Preferences -> Settings-User`) and add the following:

```json
"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true
```

Save the file, and now you'll only select the current autocomplete option when hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Also, remember that you can close the autocomplete dialog by just hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: THANK YOU!  It was soooo annoying!

Comment: Hi, this really helped me but I was wondering if there is a way of not showing the panel at all until I actually type something. The problem of having the snippet inserted got fixed, but the panel still pops up and stays there until I hit [ESC].